# Вывод данных переменной в twig

Tags: php, twig

есть проект, который использует шаблонизатор twig,

Для примера есть следующая функция на php

```
    function getFullYears($birthdayDate) {
            $datetime = new DateTime($birthdayDate);
            $interval = $datetime->diff(new DateTime(date("Y-m-d")));
            $user['age'] = $interval->format(«%Y»);}
```

В шаблоне twig вывожу как {{ user.age }}

но в ответ пустое значение (если просто вывести какие то статичные данные в функции, результат тот же).

Кто подскажет как правильно выводить переменные в твиг, или что я упускаю.

Спасибо!

Comment: ваша функция ничего не возвращает. Так что откуда вы берёте `user.age` совершенно не ясно

Answer (score 0):

Нужно рендерить

```html
    function getFullYears($birthdayDate) {
            $datetime = new DateTime($birthdayDate);
            $interval = $datetime->diff(new DateTime(date("Y-m-d")));
            $user['age'] = $interval->format(«%Y»);
            
echo $twig->render('index.html', ['user' => $user]);
            }
```